# Screen orientation in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, orientation

how to get orientation type and lock orientation in ReactJS?
The Screen Orientation API doesn't work with ReactJS or I just don't know how to install and use it. Please guide me to do the above. Thanks.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I am creating an app in reactjs, when viewed on my phone, I want it to be viewed in fullscreen landscape mode but I am not able to do it.
I want to do exactly in the below:
https://usefulangle.com/demos/105/screen.html

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is not that clear from your post. However, plain JavaScript ([`Window.matchMedia()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method) along with a bit of CSS (media query for [`orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation)) and event listener for window resize, may let you grab window orientation and store it within app state.

Following code demonstrates that concept (no live-demo due to stacksnippets limitations, so you may try that out at [stackblitz](http://react-r8rczg.stackblitz.io)):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

const rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const App = () => {
    const isLandscape = () => window.matchMedia('(orientation:landscape)').matches,
          [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(isLandscape() ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'),
          onWindowResize = () => {              
            clearTimeout(window.resizeLag)
            window.resizeLag = setTimeout(() => {
              delete window.resizeLag                       
              setOrientation(isLandscape() ? 'landscape' : 'portrait')
            }, 200)
          }

    useEffect(() => (
      onWindowResize(),
      window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize),
      () => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWindowResize)
    ),[])

    return (
      <div>{orientation}</div>
    )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

*p.s.* while above is pretty viable, it may become even more comprehensive in a short while as [`window.screen.orientation`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) (working draft currently) will make it to the standard, one more *improvement* may seem obvious (listen for [`orientationchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) event, rather than `resize`), but former doesn't seem to me working so smoothly for desktop version of the app

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. Checkout the answer i posted

Comment: `window.screen.orientation` is deprecated and no longer recommended. Try using width/height ratio, like `isLandscape = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight > 1;`

Edit: `window.orientation` is deprecated. My bad.